# CMS Made Simple: Session getting reset between page views

Tags: php, session, smarty, cmsmadesimple

I have a form in a template which is posted to a PHP script. This script sets some variables in the $_SESSION array, then redirects back to the same page using the standard:

```
header("Location: index.php?page=enquiry-form");
```

The problem is that whenever the page loads after refirection, the session only contains the following three variables:

- cmsuserkey
- cms_admin_user_id
- cms_admin_username

...all of mine have disappeared.

- I'm calling session_start(); in my php script
- I've set the config option: $config['use_smarty_php_tags'] = true;

The user doesn't need to be logged in to use the form (in fact the site doesn't use logins at all).

Can anyone suggest anything I'm not doing/doing wrong?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: I've had a similar problem once (which I've now encountered again), I believe that this problem is caused by CMS Made Simple not sharing the session with your regular PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem (though I wanted to use data from the CMS Made Simple session in another php-file). For me the cause was the following (as stated in my comment on the question):

CMS Made Simple (CMS from now on) does makes its own session name. This means that when you run session_start() in a separate php-file, it will not have the same session name. Therefore, the php-file won't be able to access CMS's session data, and CMS won't be able to access the php-file's session data.

The solution logically follows from the cause, you need them both to use the same session name.
CMS sets its session name in `include.php` which should be in the app's root folder.

```
$dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
...

$session_key = substr(md5($dirname), 0, 8);

#Setup session with different id and start it
@session_name('CMSSESSID' . $session_key);
```

So, in your php file you will need to do the following (*before* calling `session_start();`):

```
//Substitute the string $dirname for the result of __FILE__ in **include.php**!!!
$dirname = '/data/web/somefolder/someotherfolder/'
$session_key = substr(md5($dirname), 0, 8);
@session_name('CMSSESSID' . $session_key);
//Now you can call session_start();
```

Doing this lets your php-file access CMS's Session. If you use any plugins that put essential data in the session, you'll want to be careful not to erase any of that data.

NOTE: I use CMS version 1.8.2, this solution may not work if you use a different version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once and fixed it by addin exit() after the redirection to save the session:

```
 header("Location: index.php?page=enquiry-form");
 exit();
```